# Grabbing transaction fee for a list of transaction hashes

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

I want to take a set of transaction hashes pulled from my contract info on etherscan and use those to grab the transaction fee from the transaction details page, without having to manually click into each page.

Can anyone point me to the right endpoint on the api? I can't find it. I'm ideally trying to grab the dollar amount rather than the gas then having to convert manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `txlist` action of the Etherscan API to get transactions associated with a specific address. They only return raw blockchain data, not the price, so you'll need to calculate that separately.

Docs: https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address